# Wifi says cannot resolve DNS, but ethernet connection works fine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, internet

I have a WiFi network at home that's connecting via my ISP to the internet. I recently stopped getting internet access on my laptop via WiFi. All other laptops and devices can still connect without a problem.

- If I connect via ethernet to my router, then my laptop can access the internet.
- If I connect to other WiFi connections (hotspot on my mobile, the WiFi at work, etc.) the WiFi connection works fine and I can access the internet without a problem.
- I tried updating the drivers, uninstalling and re-installing the hardware, i have even migrated from win 7 to win 10, but the problem remains the same.
- I have checked if there are any blocked connections, IP's or MAC addresses on my router, but there are none.
- I have tried any and all solutions I could find on the internet - flushing DNS, resetting connections, windows' own problem resolutions etc, but no luck.

The bottom line is, my WiFi module is working fine, as it can connect to the internet on other WiFi networks, and can connect to my router. My router is not a problem, as I can connect via ethernet to the internet, and all my other devices can access the internet via the WiFi without a problem. My only guess at this stage is that my ISP might have blocked my WiFi MAC address for some or another reason?

Comment: Have you tried resetting your router/access point?

Comment: Thanks for sorting the formatting @MMM, I was struggling to read the question!

Comment: @MMM - resetting as in power cycle or internally restarting, or resetting as in factory resetting and starting from scratch? If power cycle then yes, several times, as well as resetting from the user interface. Factory resetting - no not yet, but as mentioned, none of my other devices are having issues using the same WiFi, so it's an option but I doubt if the problem is there

Comment: Have you changed DNS settings in the adapter? After using Cloudflare as DNS provider, I found some WiFi connections only allowed lookup through their default DNS service.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes I have changed, manually set, automatically detect and tried various DNS server addresses, without any luck. Trying to Ping the DNS resulted in a timeout on the WiFi connection, but responded without a problem when connected via ethernet to the router

Answer (score 0):

Reset your Winsock

> **netsh winsock reset**
>   
> Then restart your computer.

Have a look at your settings

> netsh interface tcp show global

Is there any which are disabled? (Some may be automatically disabled in Windows)

You might see ECN Capability: Disabled.

> If so type "netsh int tcp set global ecncapability=enabled" and press Enter.
>   
>   Then type "netsh int tcp set global congestionprovider=ctcp" and press Enter.
>   
>   To verify settings toke Type "netsh int tcp show global" and press Enter.

It worked for me

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-enable-explicit-congestion-notification-ecn/84baca68-49c0-47f1-93c0-7bed1bb07098

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. Did a hard factory reset on my WiFi router, re-programmed it and suddenly my Laptop's WiFi is working again. So it seems to have been something strange on the router!

Kind Regards
Hennie

Comment: @Hennie Very good, you write and answer explaining what you did, then everyone that visits your post will know you have worked it out and how you fixed the situation. Thanks for letting us know. ;-)